# Convert "for loop" from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

For this Python `for` loop:

```
for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
```

What is the equivalent code syntax in C++?

Comment: Also try reading [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: This question is currently involved in a [controversial meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403116/)

Comment: I think you can self-delete a post even if it has been forcefully un-deleted. I'm not sure why this un-deletion was done to your post. The flurry of downvotes is not going to make it easier on your account. Please read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) so you're well informed prior to a possible Question ban.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert this python for-loop using a range into C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988089/how-can-i-convert-this-python-for-loop-using-a-range-into-c)

Comment: @Scratte Given there are two answers now deleting would not be possible now.

Comment: @TheMaster Apparently now users think that the author has posted a debugging problem, since they seem to think it needs the debugging details.

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent in C++ would be

```
for(i = n-2 ; i > -1 ; --i)
  { /* whatever */ }
```